# File `expl3.sty' not found when compiling on texstudio

Tags: packages

I am trying to compile my latex document on TeXstudio but I keep on getting the following error:

> File `expl3.sty' not found. \RequirePackage{expl3}[2018/10/31]

I have tried to download the expl3 package online and put in the folder `C:\Program Files\texstudio\Packages` but it is still not working.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you have installed? TeXLive or MiKTeX?

Comment: LaTeX packages has nothing to do with texstudio. TeXStudio is an editor. Installing latex stuff is handled via the package manager for the LaTeX installation you use. So please provide information about which LaTeX installation you are using

Comment: I have MiKTeX installed